# Warning about toctree references

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   foo.rst
   bar.rst

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

I am trying to build it using `sphinx-build . doc` It gives me warning:

> ```
> (WARNING/2) toctree references unknown document u'bar'
> ```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Is ``bar.rst`` in the same dir as ``foo.rst``?  If not, can you add a sym-link for ``bar.rst`` in the directory of ``foo.rst``?

Comment: Now Both are in same directory. now  the error is -- document isn't included in any toctree.

Answer (score 3):

Sphinx doesn't need the `.rst` extension in the toctree directive. Assuming the toctree is in something like `index.rst` and `bar.rst` is in the same directory, try replacing `foo.rst` and `bar.rst` in your toctree directive with `foo` and `bar` respectively.

Otherwise, make sure `bar.rst` is in the correct directory (and not in a parent or subdirectory).

Comment: I personally have production code with the `.rst` extension for every file under the the `..toctree` example, though perhaps the `.rst` extension is optional.

Comment: I'm 99% certain I've seen an error related to the file extension with a project from work, though I don't think we're running a current version of Sphinx. So it may be version dependent.

Comment: I had errors until I removed the `.rst` extension in the `:doc:` role Sphinx version 1.4.5 so the same rule may apply throughout.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this error. For me, it was due to indentation. The "toctree" was indented by 3 space characters, whereas I listed the rst files by 4 space characters. To resolve the issue, we need to have the same indentation level.